# Is it possible to use the greedy solution to solve the problem of scheduling to minimize TOTAL lateness? How to solve it?

Tags: math, scheduling, greedy

Please help! Is it possible to use the greedy solution to solve the problem of scheduling to minimize total lateness? How to solve it?

I understood the problem of scheduling to minimize maximum lateness and wanted to know how to solve the problem of scheduling to minimize total lateness. I searched through the internet and have not found a single solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the greedy solution", and I may have misunderstood your question, however have you considered *tardiness* as a performance measure?

While lateness is typically linear, and will be negative for jobs completed before the due date,

[image]

Tardiness can be thought of as,

[image]

Which is slightly nicer to work with, and some googling will reveal heuristics such as ATC to help you solve this, depending on the rest of your problem parameters.

Where

[image]

It would not be too hard to write an IP formulation to minimise the sum of tardinesses which can be defined by this constraint, given that you are not "set" on using a heuristic.

[image]

Where

[image]